# CMake: Static libraries not linking correctly with second project

Tags: c++, cmake

Let me preface this by saying I'm quite new to CMake, so please let me know if I'm just misunderstanding something here.

First I'm compiling a static library that acts as a wrapper to an external program (Paraview).  The CMakeLists file I use to create this library is like so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(POP)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY [LIBRARY HOME]/lib/)


 set(ParaView_DIR [PARAVIEW HOME]/ParaView-v5.4.1/)

  find_package(ParaView REQUIRED COMPONENTS vtkPVPythonCatalyst)
  include("${PARAVIEW_USE_FILE}")


 if(NOT PARAVIEW_USE_MPI)
    message(SEND_ERROR "ParaView must be built with MPI enabled")
    endif()

  set(HEADER_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/pop_API.h ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/pop_API_vars.h ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/pop_Structures.h ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/wrapper_pop_API.h)

  add_library(POP STATIC src/pop_API.cpp src/wrapper_pop_API.cpp src/pop_Adaptor.cpp ${HEADER_FILES})
  target_include_directories(POP PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)          
  target_link_libraries(POP LINK_PUBLIC vtkPVPythonCatalyst)
  include(vtkModuleMacros)
  include(vtkMPI)
  vtk_mpi_link(POP)
```

This links in a specific Paraview module I need, and some VTK datastructures that are required for that as well.

This CMake file runs just fine, and I can compile the libraries no problem.  If I add a Main function to my C++ code and compile it as an executable, that runs no problem as well.  So everything *seems* fine here.

Now, I ultimately want this static library to be called by a second piece of code.  To test this I've written a toy C++ project that just calls the main functions of this library

```
#include "pop_Structures.h"
#include "pop_API.h" 

int main()
    {
      PopGrid* grid;
      PopSolution* solution;
      a = 1;
      b = 2;
      int x = POP_INITIALIZE(a, b);
      int y = COPROCESS(PopGrid, PopSolution, a, b, a, b);
      int z = POP_FINALIZE();
}
```

The included header files just define the PopSolution and PopGrid structures, as well as the prototypes for the three functions being called.  I create the executable for this program using a CMakeLists file that looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(CPP_Test)

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
  include_directories(${MPI_CXX_INCLUDE_PATH})  

  set(HEADER_FILES [LIBRARY HOME]/include/pop_API.h [LIBRARY HOME]/include/pop_Structures.h)

  ADD_EXECUTABLE(CPP_TEST CPP_Test.cpp ${HEADER_FILES})
  target_include_directories(CPP_TEST PUBLIC [LIBRARY HOME]/include)
  target_link_libraries(CPP_TEST[LIBRARY HOME]/lib/libPOP.a)
```

This CMake also runs just fine, but when I compile it I get a number of undefined reference errors pointing to functions in libPOP.a where I refer to VTK/Paraview data structures and functions.  These are not directly defined in the toy code above, but they *should* be defined in the library, correct?  If these structures are all defined when I compile the initial library, why are they not defined when I call that library externally?

Thanks.

Comment: `These are not directly defined in the toy code above, but they should be defined in the library, correct?` - No, your `POP` library doesn't define symbols from `ParaView` one. So, when link with your library, you still need to link with `ParaView`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, is there anyway to make the library fully self-contained?  For a number of reasons directly linking Paraview and my final code is extremely messy.

Comment: If by "self-contained" you mean that your library will define symbols from ParaView, then you need to compile code of those libraries together. Or build static variant of libraries, and combine them into single static library (google for that). If by "self-contained" you mean that linking with "Paraview" will be performed automatically when one links your library, you need to create shared library instead of static.

Comment: Okay great, that's actually very helpful!